how to parse full node binary response in python
I have launched a devnet on my local to play around with the Alephium crypto node. According to the mining docs, it says the response given is:
# The mining pool communicates with the full node through a binary protocol, 
# the format of the message is as follows:

MessageSize(4 bytes) + Message(1 byte MessageType + Payload)

What i've done is

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    data = s.recv(14967)

    print(len(data))  # --> length is 6985 for first call
    print(unpack_from("!iB", data, 0))  # size[4bytes] + msgType[1byte]
    msg_size = unpack_from("!i", data, 0)[0]  # need to -1 from msgSize because of msgtype 1 byte
    
    # Payload should be
    print(unpack_from("!6980s", data, 5))  # currently unpacks all into single byte

As expected the result from the payload unpacking gives me: b'\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01E <truncated> ... 
my question is: according to stratum, i need to get a jsonrpc response, and submit a jsonrpc request thereafter. But I cannot understand how to parse the binary response out to something usable..
Any tips will be appreciated.
